# Easy way to generate colour-per-vertex models for input to Blender

Tags: color, file-format, vertex-attribute, face

I procedurally generate [3D planet models](https://i.redd.it/gnmga9sbz6y21.png) that I would like to import into Blender.

I use colour per vertex rendering in my shaders (In practice, I use the same colour for all vertices of a face, but my vertex attributes include RGBA.)

I like generating wavefront **.obj** files, because the syntax is so easy. But wavefront obj [does not let me specify colour per vertex](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21303/how-can-i-include-vertex-color-information-in-obj-files), or colour per face. Instead, the entire object is coloured with a material from the material-library that accompanies the obj geometry file.

I've looked into collada **.dae** as well, but frankly, that seems like a very [complex format](https://www.khronos.org/files/collada_spec_1_5.pdf), and it still seems to work with material libraries, like the .obj format does.

Is there an easy to generate 3d model format that lets me specify a colour per vert (or face) without material libraries, and can be imported into Blender?

Comment: I wouldn't be a neat solution, but you could export your color data as a texture, and use it in an .mtl file referenced by the .obj file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Stanford's [.PLY](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/) Polygon File Format is the winner here.

Although, after the import into Blender, [some actions are required](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36859/20781) to actually see the colours.

PLY supports colour-per-vertex and colour-per-face, but I've found that Blender can only handle the colour-per-vertex files.